# Creating target/action pairs in code

Tags: iphone

I have a custom UITableViewCell that I want to have an action for when a UISegmentedControl (in the tableviewcell) is pressed.  So I created the code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this:

```
static NSString *SortByCellIdentifier = @"SortByCellIdentifier";
        SortByTableViewCell *cell = (SortByTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SortByCellIdentifier];
        [cell.SortBySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(SortBySegmentedControlPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I don't ever remember doing anything in the .xib of that cell, but when I click on the File'sOwner (which is of type SortByTableViewCell), I get this picture:

[image]

After running it, it works.  By adding the line: [cell.SortBySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(SortBySegmentedControlPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

does that create the action for me in IB as seen in the screenshot?  The reason I ask is because I do that with some other cells as well, and the methods never get called.  And when I check the .xib of those UITableViewCells, there is no action wired up like in the screenshot.  So I'm wondering if maybe I did do something in IB and just don't remember it or something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the action correctly, but where are you creating cell.SortBySegmentedControl and adding it to the cell's contentView? If it works you must be doing that somewhere. That's probably what you need to do to get the other cases to work.

Comment: I'm doing it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method since that's where the custom cell is getting created.  That's the only place I do cell.SortBySegmentedControl.  For some reasons, the other cells' actions are not getting created.

Comment: Post the code for those cells then? Post the code that doesn't work, not the code that does work.